# numpy multiple random choice

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to generate multiple random choices without replacement from a range with `numpy`.

For example - I want that my output will be a 2D array, with `x` lines, where each line has exactly `y` randomly chosen numbers from the given range.

[`numpy.random.Generator.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html#numpy.random.Generator.choice) function can choose values, but you can't use the `size` parameter for each line separately (it represents the total number of choices)

I can call `choice` in a loop, but I'm looking for something more efficient.

My current code:

```
rand = numpy.random.default_rng()
output = numpy.zeros((x,y))

for i in range(x):
    output[i, :] = rand.choice(x, y, replace=False, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: So you mean the range is always fixed to `x`?

Comment: x is a variable, but once set, the range is fixed

Comment: Yes! this is a good direction, though I'm not sure about the mathematical correctness of this method. I think that for practical usage it'll be enough. Thanks!